# CSS float and HTML questions

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have some questions about basic CSS that I was unable to understand or find an answer for.

First, I tried placing 3 div tags within another div tag. The first main div tag containing the 3 other tags had nothing set for it except a size, which was `400px` by `400px`. Of the other 3 divs inside, all were `20px` by `20px`, and 1 was assigned `float:left`, and the other two were assigned a style that was float right. All attributes were defined within a style, and the two divs that were `float:right` were assigned the same style. My problem is that out of the 2 divs, the one that came last in the code, would appear first in a browser, and I did not understand the reasoning for this.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#main{ 
    border: red 4px dashed;
    width: 25%
    height: 25%,
    }
#left{ 
    float: left;    
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px,
    }
#right{ 
    float: right;   
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px,
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<div id="left">1</div>
<div id="right">2</div>
<div id="right">3</div>
</div>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: you probably shouldn't have two DIVS with an id of "right" -- ids are supposed to be unique.

Comment: agreed - change the 'id="left/right"' to 'class="left/right"' (arguments about semantics aside), and change your css to ".left" and ".right"

Comment: Can I suggest separating out your questions? It'll make it easier for people to give specific answers :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My problem is that out of the 2 divs,
>   the one that came last in the code,
>   would appear first in a browser, and I
>   did not understand the reasoning for
>   this.

I think that You misunderstood a "appear first". You set Your divs to be floating right. So a "2" div, which is FIRST in Your code, is FIRST to be floated right, so it goes first to the right side. A "3" div is then floated, so i goes to the left side of the "2" div - because "2" was first, it took first place at the right side of the browser window, and div "3" took second place at the right side of the window.

In this case "second place at the right side of the window" means "first, looking from the left" ;-)

Comment: +1 this is correct - the other answers are pointing out some other issues with the code sample, but they don't address the problem. this answer explains what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

At first, I would use class and not id for the divs. But there are also some typo's in the css:

```
#main{ 
    border: red 4px dashed;
    width: 25%;  /* <-- Missing ; */
    height: 25%; /* <-- change , to ; */
}
#left{ 
    float: left;        
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px; /* <-- change , to ; */
}
#right{ 
    float: right;       
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px; /* <-- change , to ; */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the layering problem, but you can't have two elements with the same ID. You probably want:

```
...
<div class="right">2</div>
<div class="right">3</div>
...
```

and change `#right` to `.right` in the CSS.

Comment: that won't change his situation though. though it's not valid HTML, the browser still will render the CSS "correctly"

Comment: Perhaps, but I assumed that if you're doing something "illegal", the browser is free to interpret it whatever way it wants, which may not give you what you expect depending on the browser. I figure the best way to *start* is to have correct HTML.

Comment: you're correct in general, but in this case, it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are using id instead of class. An ID is supposed to be unique, so the second div with id="right" is the only one with that id.

You could change your code such that you have:

< div class="right" >2< /div >

< div class="right" >3< /div >

(instead of id="right")

And in the css you would have:

.right {

```
float: right;       

width: 20px;

height: 20px,

}
```

(instead of #right)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
<div id="main">
        <div id="left">1</div>
        <div id="right">3</div>
        <div id="right">2</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the same id for more than one time.

```
<div class="right">2</div>
<div class="right">3</div>
```

Better way you can do it with assigning class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#main{ 
    border: red 4px dashed;
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
}
.left{ 
    float: left;    
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
.right{ 
    float: right;   
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <div class="left">1</div>
    <div class="right">3</div>
    <div class="right">2</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Changes made:

Replaced commas with semicolons in the CSS properties.
Changed duplicate IDs to classes.
Changed the order of the last two divs within the main div to control their appearance order.

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#main {
    border: 4px dashed red;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#left {
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px,
}
#right {
    float: right;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px,
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
  <div id="left">1</div>
  <div id="right">3</div>
  <div id="right">2</div>
</div>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: The answer, while valid code, does not explain WHY you changed what you changed.